# Boolean checkbox in sytems_settings_form

Tags: 7, forms

I have written the following code

```
$form['checking'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('checking',0),
    '#title' => t('title'),
    '#required' => TRUE
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
```

the checkbox preserve its checked and unchecked state in the form but I can't get value of the checkbox.

I'm printing its value

```
dsm(variable_get('checking);
print_r(variable_get('checking',0));
```

Whether a checkbox is checked or unchecked, in both cases it returns me `1`

How can I know whether the checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the "#required" => TRUE line? If you uncheck the checkbox and the form item is required the form won't validate and your submit callback will not be called.

Also, you should check that your variable isn't overridden in settings.php https://www.drupal.org/node/1525472

Comment: Yes, remove `#required => TRUE` if the form should be able to be submitted with the checkbox unchecked. If the form *shouldn't* be able to be submitted without the checkbox being checked, there's no need to get the value as it's always going to be TRUE.

Answer (score -1):

hmmm, looks like you're print_r'ing the result from *variable_get()* - ie. you're unwillingly asking "did *variable_get()* run correctly?"

try storing the result from *variable_get* in a variable then print_r'ing that. or use *dsm()* instead (from the **[Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)** module).

cheers, 
Luco

Comment: I have also tried with dsm, it is mentioned in the question

Comment: oops. well anyway, try storing it in a variable then.